# jvmti and Spring AOP conflict

Tags: java, spring, aop, jvmti

Background:
I'm doing something to encrypt Java .class file, and using jvmti agentlib to decrypt the source data when the .class file is loaded.
It's working when I do this for Java SE.

But some exceptions are thrown when I do this for a java web project using Spring AOP.

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:Failed to read candidate component class
```

The .class file can be read by `ContextLoaderListener`, of course, it's encrypted, but why doesn't the AOP load it with the jvmti agentlib?

It seems that Spring AOP loads the .class file without jvmti agentlib

Is there some relation between jvmti and AOP?
I want to know more about this problem.